# Enable milestone field in TRAC ticket form

Tags: trac, milestone

Using Trac 1.4, I have TRAC_ADMIN priviledges. A project has been defined and I created a number of milestones in the form of version identifiers (eg 1.2.3).

I would now expect a Milestone field with my defined values to be presented as a select-option in the 'new ticket' form, but it is not. Milestone is a column of the ticket table as documented at https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports

How can I configure the milestone field to be displayed in ticket forms?

I came across this page: https://www.singular.uni-kl.de:8005/trac/newticket where it is visible, admittedly that is running Trac 1.2.3, but it demonstrates this should be possible and has been in the past.

Comment: Does `[trac] permission_policies` in trac.ini include `DefaultTicketPolicy`?

Comment: Thank you @RjOllos, DefaultTicketPolicy was not in the config, after adding it the Milestone selector appeared! If you suggest this as answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion from RjOllos fixed the issue, `DefaultTicketPolicy` added to `permission_policies` in the `[trac]` section of trac.ini, and the Milestone selector appeared.